# How can I reference resx files in a Silverlight RIA Services Library?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm a Silverlight newbie.  When I create a silverlight 4 business application in Visual Studio 2010, the web application has a resource folder with resx files. The silverlight application has a folder web/resources/ then there are two 2 resx files in there named the same as the 2 in the web app.  They have little arrow icons on them indicating they are linked or copied or generated or something. They point to the files in the web app.  Now when I create a RIA Services Class Library, there are no resx files in the default template. If I add them, how can I make the silverlight app in the ria service library see and reference those files the way the business application is doing? I add the resx files and build and they are not copied to the silverlight app. If I manually add them to the silverlight app, they are independent files when they should be pointing to the ones in the ria services library web app. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong and how I can get the files to behave the way I'm intending?  I hope you can understand my question.

Thanks for any help,
~ck in San Diego